# What is the difference between "to assuage somebody" and "to soothe somebody"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, vocabulary

What is the difference between "to assuage somebody" and "to soothe somebody"

Both words have pretty similar meanings.

Comment: So you can't, for example, assuage a baby, right?

Comment: You can assuage a baby's hunger, or soothe a baby's pain, or soothe a baby. You cannot assuage a baby.

Answer (score 1):

You can assuage a feeling, pain, or desire; you can soothe these things, and also soothe a person. You cannot assuage a person.

[Assuage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assuage)

[Soothe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soothe)